# RequireJS 2.3.5 - how to work with JQuery 3.2 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: requirejs

I have tried a lot for setting up RequireJS 2.3.5 with Query 3.2 and Bootstrap 3.3.7, but still get below error (i know the third error is caused by jquery is not loaded successfully), any ideas? thanks.

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Below is my setting:

**main.js**

```
  requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "lib/js",
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": ["jquery"]
    }
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="lib/js/require.min.js" data-main="lib/js/main"></script>

<script>
  require(["jquery", "bootstrap"], function($) {
     $('.bar').click( function() {
        //...
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The jQuery URL you are trying to load returns a 404 for me. This also explains the error message, as the browser is trying to parse an HTML file (the error page) as JS.

Comment: but requirejs should automatically add the .js at the end of the URL, so it should become //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js  , it means it should be ok to load (no 404 error)

Comment: found that if I change it to  require(["jquery"], function($) { ... , just one error message: "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' " is shown instead of two errors